# How to set the default option value in SingleSelectField?

Tags: python, turbogears2, toscawidgets

I'm new to Turbogears 2.3.3 and Toscawidgets 2. Could anyone tell me how to set the default value based on the id?

**URL**:  .../view?id=2

**FormWidget**:

```
FruitForm(twf.Form):  
    class child(twf.TableLayout):  
        fruit=twf.SingleSelectField(options=DBsession.query(Fruit.id, Fruit.name)
```

**Model**: Fruit
id, name

**Controller**:

```
@expose ('view')  
def view(self, id)  
    fruit=DBSession.query(Fruit).get(id)  
    return dict(page='view', value=fruit, form=FruitForm(action='/save')
```

**Template**:

```
<div>${form.display(value=value)}</div>
```

**Question**:
When the url is /view?id=2, in the SingleSelectField how to display the fruit whose id is 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two errors in your snippet:

The first is that `options` are loaded without using `Deferred` which causes the query to be executed on application startup (when the form is imported) and not when the form is displayed which is probably not what you want.

The second is that you are setting as form value the fruit itself, while the value in case of a form should be a dictionary of the children values (as form actually have multiple values, one for each child).

I created a short example on Runnable of a possible working solution: http://runnable.com/U-tO4xSN7Ch6wWS7/turbogears-forms-fill-singleselect-value-for-pythonpos

Comment: Thanks @amol. The use of `Deferred` really saved my day. Regarding to the second thing, I followed the turbogears cookbook on the official website and read that all the fields have to be specified in the `Child` class. In my case above, apart from singleselectfield, I have some other fields. My qustion is that how to pass the parameter to `birthday` if `BirthdayForm` is a child of `FruitForm`?

Comment: It's right to specify the fields into the `child` subclass, it permits to keep separated layout and form itself, but it doesn't change the form behaviour. I updated the example to use `Form->TableLayout` hierarchy but as you can you still need to pass the values of the form as a `dict`: `form_values=dict(birthday=today)`